# In VSCode, how can I disable the GCC warnings in the problems window (I'm not compiling with GCC and I only use clangd extension)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

I'm using CMake with clang to compile.
I'm using only the clangd VSCode extension (i.e., not using any other C++ extensions).

In the "Problems" window, which is powered by VSCode and not compiler output (so there's not an issue with my CMake stuff or compile_commands.json, because I don't even have to compile to see the Problems messages):

- Some error blah blah - clang [Ln x, Col y]
- Some error blah blah - GCC [Ln x, Col y]

The first error is presumably from clangd and I want to keep it.
How can I get rid of the second error?  I'm not using GCC anywhere in my build, so I don't know how it got there.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you compile your code?

Comment: CMake was run with CXX=clang++ and CC=clang and Ninja output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm adding my answer bacause the previous one doesn't remove the warnings and errors from code

settings UI ->
Cmake: Enabled Output Parsers ->
remove gcc from the  list

or in settings.json define your own list ( this is how it looks for me):

"cmake.enabledOutputParsers": ["cmake", "gnuld", "ghs", "diab"]

Comment: Thank you for putting this here, it definitely addresses the issue more directly.  Great answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the filter in the "problems" tab. Write clang to remove gcc entries.

Comment: This doesn't remove the errors, it just hides them. Also they are still shown in the editor.